# How do I get the enemy to chase the player? I would also like to know how to jump onto the moving object when I jump and not just go through it

Tags: python, pygame

moving object. It currently moves left and right across the screen and I would like the user to be able to jump on it.

```
def moving_object():
    global x_speed, y_speed
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (200, 140, 150), rectangle)
    rectangle.x += x_speed

    if rectangle.right >= 500 or rectangle.left <= 0:
        x_speed *= -1
```

class for my enemy. They currently move left and right across the screen but I would like them to follow the user. They can also not jump

```
class enemy():
    walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1E.png'), pygame.image.load('R2E.png'), pygame.image.load('R3E.png'), pygame.image.load('R4E.png'), pygame.image.load('R5E.png'), pygame.image.load('R6E.png'), pygame.image.load('R7E.png'), pygame.image.load('R8E.png'), pygame.image.load('R9E.png'), pygame.image.load('R10E.png'), pygame.image.load('R11E.png')]
    walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1E.png'), pygame.image.load('L2E.png'), pygame.image.load('L3E.png'), pygame.image.load('L4E.png'), pygame.image.load('L5E.png'), pygame.image.load('L6E.png'), pygame.image.load('L7E.png'), pygame.image.load('L8E.png'), pygame.image.load('L9E.png'), pygame.image.load('L10E.png'), pygame.image.load('L11E.png')]

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.end = end
        self.WalkCount = 0
        self.vel = 3
        self.path = [self.x, self.end]
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
        self.health = 10
        self.visible = True

    def draw(self, win):
        self.move()
        if self.visible:
            if self.WalkCount + 1 >= 33:
                self.WalkCount = 0
            if self.vel > 0:
                win.blit(self.walkRight[self.WalkCount //3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.WalkCount += 1
            else:
                win.blit(self.walkLeft[self.WalkCount //3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.WalkCount += 1

            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50, 10))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50, 10))
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)

    def move(self):
        if self.vel > 0:
            if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.WalkCount = 0
        else:
            if self.x - self.vel > self.path[0]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.WalkCount = 0

    def hit(self):
        if self.health > 0:
            self.health -= 1
        else:
            self.visible = False
        pass
```

Comment: for following there is just an option to just increase their coords towards player coords, so nothing fancy and they are gonna go very straight. basically You set a coordinate that is the player current coordinate and in the game loop add or decrease x and y coordinates for enemies until You get to that position, otherwise You have to create a bit more complex pathfinding algorithm (the simplest is the one I already told You about tho You can just make them teleport which will be much easier)

Answer (score 0):

So here is one way to make a pathfinding algorithm:

```
import pygame
import time


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 500))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

to_coords = [550, 100]
from_coords = (150, 400)


def go_to_koeff(from_, to):
    dx = to[0] - from_[0]
    dy = to[1] - from_[1]

    if dx != 0:
        dx /= abs(dx)
    if dy != 0:
        dy /= abs(dy)

    return dx, dy


follow_coords_x = from_coords[0]
follow_coords_y = from_coords[1]
velocity = 1


run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), to_coords, 5)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), from_coords, 5)

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), (follow_coords_x, follow_coords_y), 5)
    koeff = go_to_koeff((follow_coords_x, follow_coords_y), to_coords)
    follow_coords_x += velocity * koeff[0]
    follow_coords_y += velocity * koeff[1]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        to_coords[1] -= 3
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        to_coords[1] += 3
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        to_coords[0] -= 3
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        to_coords[0] += 3

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

so basically the whole algorithm is that `go_to_koeff()` function: that function returns the koefficent of direction that can be used to change where the white dot moves that can be seen where the coefficient is multiplied by velocity. This algorithm isn't perfect but it finds the position so there is that. (You can play around a bit by moving the green dot with arrow keys to see how it moves)

Another idea that came to mind was tracking player position in a list and making the enemy follow all the coords in the list which could be even worse but it will feel like it is actually following You.

Also I just noticed that there is some useless change of variable names, but it doesn't affect anything much.